# react on datepicker click want to change toggle value

Tags: reactjs, toggle, material-ui

I'm developing Flight API. when user click on return journey field I want to toggle button from single trip to round trip ( false to true).

```
<DatePicker
  hintText="Return Date"
  errorText={this.state.journeyDateErrorText}
  onChange={(event, value) => {                                                    
  this.setState({journeyDate: value})
  }}
  minDate={new Date()}      
  onClick={this.enableReturnDate.bind(this)}
  />
```

above is my datepicker field when user click on this field I want to toggle my toggle component from false (single trip) to true (round trip).

```
<Toggle
 thumbSwitchedStyle={{backgroundColor: 'grey'}}
 onToggle={this.handleonToggle.bind(this)}
 label={this.state.tripType}
 defaultToggled={false}
 />
```

to get result that I want I have added onClick event and change state of toggle that is show as lable **this.state.tripType**.

```
enableReturnDate(e){

    this.setState({
        tripType: 'Round Trip'
    })
}
```

after add onClick event toggle state **this.state.tripType** is changed from single trip to round trip but I want to change toggle button too from false to true.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You should control the toggle component through state,

```
<Toggle
     thumbSwitchedStyle={{backgroundColor: 'grey'}}
     onToggle={this.handleonToggle.bind(this)}
     label={this.state.tripType}
     defaultToggled={this.state.toggleState} // control toggle state by state
     />

    // keep the toggle state as false initially, and change it to true when datePicker has been clicked or changed

enableReturnDate(e){
        this.setState({
            tripType: 'Round Trip',
            toggleState: true  //dont forget the initialize the state as false in constructor
        })
    }
```